# Secure Login Forms

Tags: security, ssl

At present there doesn't seem to be an easy way to login securely using the Member module. [Safecraker provides useful parameters in secure_action="yes" and secure_return="yes"](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/#secure-action) to ensure encrypted submissions but the login form is left wide open by default (which is a unbelievable!).

How do other people handle secure login form submissions to ensure they are posted over HTTPS in the lack of a built in facility by default in EE?

I know that [FreeMember has recently has this support added](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/issues/25) but if I'm not using FreeMember than I'd like to be able to find a way to secure my logins.

**UPDATE**: It looks like [Zoo Visitor also supports secure login forms](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/9114) and it's [now just been added to the docs](http://ee-zoo.com/docs/visitor/tags/login.html) with the same parameters as Safecracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I think this solution works best. Using a combination of [DM Force SSL](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dm-force-ssl) to ensure that that template is served over HTTPS, and [Find and Replace Plus](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/find-and-replace-plus) to swap out 'http' with 'https'. They can be used in combination with the default Login form to provide a secure login:

```
{!-- Load the page over SSL --}
{exp:dm_force_ssl:force}

{!-- Ensure the form submits over HTTPS --}
{exp:replace_plus find='action="http:' replace='action="https:'}
    {exp:member:login_form id="login_form"}

        Login form...

    {/exp:member:login_form}
{/exp:replace_plus}
```

I've also submitted a feature request to EllisLab to try and get secure_action="yes" and secure_return="yes" included in the default Member module login form.

FreeMember and Zoo Visitor provide ready-made alternatives if using those modules and Authenticate goes some way towards providing some security too but I'm not sure it's fully encrypted...(?) Thanks Tyssen.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticate has a [secure_return](https://www.objectivehtml.com/authenticate/documentation/tag/login-form#return) parameter. Will that do the trick?

Comment: Ideally it would need a secure_action too to encrypt the submission. Interesting option though. I haven't used that addon before and it seems to enhance the default login form handling which is useful.